# Disabling text input on MUI DateTimePicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datetimepicker

I have a MUI `DateTimePicker` in my react app, and I would like to disable the text input so that it is only possible to change the date/time by clicking on the icon and launching the overlays to edit them.

I have tried a few things, such as adding `disabled={true}` to the `renderInput`, like this:

```
renderInput={(params: any) => <TextField
                {...params}
                disabled={true}
                InputProps={{...params.InputProps, disableUnderline: true}}
                variant="standard"/>}
```

Doesn't quite work as expected though. I have tried a lot of other things too, but not sure how that detail would support my question.

Suggestions?

Comment: Can you also attach a reproducible [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) or [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) link which will help us debug the issue and playaround with the code?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `readOnly` to the `inputProps` which will be passed down to the native html input element will do the trick. This also leaves the MUI component in its "normal" visual state.

```js
<TextField
  {...params}
  disabled={true}
  InputProps={{...params.InputProps, disableUnderline: true}}
  inputProps={{ ...params.inputProps, readOnly: true }}
  variant="standard"
/>
```

Comment: I had done this, but there is some strange behaviour in that pressing delete or backspace when in the field variously causes the value to be set to zero under the cursor; or sometimes for the entire date/time to vanish altogether. I would love to share the code, but you know, NDAs...

Comment: @serlingpa - I was not able to reproduce the issue you're talking about. I also was not able to get my cursor in/on the input at all since it was read only. I wonder if that could be something browser related?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do exactly what you're asking by just adding the disabled prop to the TextField in renderInput.

```
<DateTimePicker
  label="Date&Time picker"
  value={value}
  onChange={handleChange}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} disabled />}
/>
```

It's possible that you are trying to set the disabled property to true when it just assumes the property being on the component means it is disabled.

Comment: Hmm...am I missing something? I see no `disabled` in that code. In any case, when I do add that, I get strange behaviour in that the field is still "somewhat" editable, but deleting causes the values to change in unexpected ways. If absolutely necessary, I will create a codesandbox. Not done one before.

Comment: I apologize. I thought that was the link to the code sandbox I had created but it's not. I will edit it to include a code snippet instead.